# React and react-router. If I create a component it calls render(). If not a component it is good without render(). It's crazy

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, react-native, react-router

Here is the link to [Sandbox](http://codesandbox.io/s/34r1l9wl4m)

I have simple code like this:

**Sidebar.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

import Menu from "./Menu";

class SidebarExample extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("Sidebar - render()", new Date());
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <div>
            If I uncomment the below component Menu the render() method of the component is called everytime I change the link. Why? In the Menu component the is the same html code below. What is going on?
            {/*<Menu />*/}
            <ul>
              <li>
                <NavLink exact to="/">
                  Home
                </NavLink>
              </li>
              <li>
                <NavLink to="/bubblegum">Bubblegum</NavLink>
              </li>
              <li>
                <NavLink to="/shoelaces">Shoelaces</NavLink>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default SidebarExample;
```

**Menu.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

class Menu extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log("Menu - render()", new Date());
    return (
      <ul>
        <li>
          <NavLink exact to="/">
            Home
          </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/bubblegum">Bubblegum</NavLink>
        </li>
        <li>
          <NavLink to="/shoelaces">Shoelaces</NavLink>
        </li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

If I uncomment the  component the render() method of the component is called everytime I change the link. Why? In the Menu component there is the same html code below.

**What is going on?**

I'm loosing my mind!

Comment: Even when i comment the `<Menu />` render() is still called inside SidebarExample , correct me if i am wrong ?

Comment: Just one time. Not everytime I change the link. I updated question with this particular. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

After testing this out for a while...I've come to the conclusion that the `render()` function, at least for v4, will apparently always run on route change...and technically, it has to run always in case there are routers in the child component.

However, just because `render()` is running on every route change, does not mean the actual component is being rebuilt. This is more apparent when you try to console log within `componentDidMount()`, `componentWillUnmount()`, or even the `constructor()`.

Here's a test with that conclusion: https://codesandbox.io/s/oxz8j04vnz

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Rey.